# How to access the result of a 2-columns grouping in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I ran a grouping by two columns and applied a function to that `df.groupby(['is_registered', 'user_id']).apply(tests_scores_avg)` which produced a new unlabeled column in a multi-index series.

The result looks like this:

```
Out[39]:
is_registered     user_id
False             2          0.666667
                  4          0.666667
                  18         0.428571
                  19         0.500000
                  20         0.666667
                  21         1.000000
                  24         0.684211
...
True              69414      0.000000
                  69416      1.000000
                  69417      0.666667
                  69429      1.000000
                  69433      1.000000
                  69434      1.000000
Length: 119276, dtype: float64
```

How can I access only the rows equal to 'False' or 'True' and get their unnamed column values? (would like to plot them)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you currently have is a `Series` with a `MultiIndex`, so all the usual rules will apply.  If your result is called `res`, then `res.ix[False]` gives you just the Falses, indexed now by only `user_id`.  Likewise for `res.ix[True]`.  See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html).